# Pipenv keeps pointing to existing virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Whenever I want to create a new virtual environment in an empty directory, pipenv always points to an existing environment although I'm not in that environment. Notice how it also creates the Pipfile in the directory where pipenv points to, instead of the current directory:

```
[philippbunke@fedora market_maker]$ pipenv --python 3.10
Virtualenv already exists!
Removing existing virtualenv...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/philippbunke/Programs/repos/work/playground/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.6) to create virtualenv...
⠋ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.6.final.0-64 in 558ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/philippbunke/.local/share/virtualenvs/playground-QFVQT-z1, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/philippbunke/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.3.1, setuptools==58.3.0, wheel==0.37.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /home/philippbunke/.local/share/virtualenvs/playground-QFVQT-z1
```

Does anyone has an idea where this is coming from?

P.S.
When I try to install a package I get the following error:

```
[philippbunke@fedora market_maker]$ pipenv install qpsolvers
Installing qpsolvers...
Adding qpsolvers to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 

CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python>=3.6 (from versions: none)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 743, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 704, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 685, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1370, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1099, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/philippbunke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 877, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python>=3.6
```